# JDBC connection to SQL Server using Windows Authentication for a different user

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a Java application that needs to connect to a SQL Server database using a domain account and windows authentication. The domain account that needs to connect is not the logged on user on the server. Is it possible to use this account and still connect?

I've tried `integratedSecurity=true;useNTLMv2=true;domain=myDomain;user=myDomainUser;password=myPassword` but it still uses the logged on user and the connection fails. Anyway around this?

Comment: Did you follow the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 ?

Comment: Are you using msjdbc or jtds

Comment: I’m using msjdbc and I had tried what David suggested but kept getting an exception saying the login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication even though the domain was trusted. It turns out the service account was locked and once it was unlocked I was able to connect. The error message certainly could use some improvement and I’d have saved a lot of time.

Comment: Have you tried to use it with runas? We are struggeling with such things since longer and to use runas was the only working solution we found.